# How to add small tips or messages in my app, should I use a library?

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience

I am new in Android development. I am trying to add the new thing in my app. Then I found the app on play store looks awesome. I am searching how to add this  but I could not found the answer.

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: Simple set background image and FloatingActionButton for downloading

Comment: @Gursewak Singh thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have manually created a shape like showing in the picture. If you want to use in your project then just use layout_background.xml file as background to your layout.

**layout_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:width="1dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#9308"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="400dp"/>

</shape>
```

**exmaple.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_background">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Happy to help you :)